# AngularJS .Net WebAPI Upload image and save to database (MSSQL)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload an Image(can be bind to a model with a data type byte[]) from UI and save it in the database.
I'm using AngularJS connecting it to .NET WebAPI and saving it to MSSSQL Server
I cant find a good example using these technologies.

Question:
What approach is better to use? like ng-upload, FormData, ArrayBuffer, convert image to byte, etc. and how will you catch it from WebAPI?

Thanks!

Comment: As to the strategy of storing blobs or files refer to this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347461/saving-images-files-or-blobs

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on this feature these days. I share my experience (obviously it can be improved).
The key components I use are:

- [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)
- [.NET ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/docs): for resizing original image for thumbnails (excellent work by Nathanael Jones)

the stack is:

**Angular.js Image Uploader**

As I said, I use angular-file-uploader. There's no so much to add to the official documentation, but [my uploader configuration](https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-web/commit/92dadfab2a1368c1e1fb99a56f05471aca6b1bb9#diff-4f9664d5a3066b2f4d6f4955c74555cfR51) is:

```
$scope.uploader = $fileUploader.create({
    scope: $scope,
    url: DisciturSettings.apiUrl + 'User/Image',
    queueLimit: 1,
    formData: [{ UserId: AuthService.user.userid }],
    headers: AuthService.getTokenHeader()
});
```

In order to send the user id to the http request and to grant the access to the authorized route

**WebApi 2 Action**

The service does the main work. Here is the [code](https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-api/commit/0cc55c0aad19c2aa84e11f85841307ab949447ae#diff-fd0147e59371266e62d9e6ea27a38ad7R130).
As you can see, in this phase, I do two resizings of the image passed (one for the user profile picture and the other for user thumbnail picture). Besides this, I convert the byte[] in string and prepare the string for next retrievals. Doing this I prepend this part "data:image/gif;base64,", so, in the next entity readings (through EntityFramework) I don't have to manipulate the result anymore and I can put them directly in angular template:

```
<img ng-src="{{local.user.image}}" />
```

Obviously It can be made differently, but that's my case.

**Database**

At the moment I simply use nvarchar for storing images.

It's my first try so it can be improved for sure (if you have hints, don't hesitate).

Comment: Do you have an example of how you're saving to the db? esp if you're streaming it in.

Comment: In my answer you can find all the code, in particular [the service used to save the images to the db](https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-api/blob/master/Controllers/UserController.cs#L133),