# C# saving images to MySql database as blob

Tags: c#, mysql

For some reason my code fails when I try to update the image for a user. The image is not saved properly. For instance an image of 38 kib is saved as 13 bytes in the database.

This is my code:

```
    public void UploadImage(Image img)
    {
        OpenConnection();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("", conn);
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE User SET UserImage = '@UserImage' WHERE UserID = '" + UserID.globalUserID + "';";
        byte[] data = imageToByte(img);
        MySqlParameter blob = new MySqlParameter("@UserImage", MySqlDbType.Blob, data.Length);
        blob.Value = data;

        command.Parameters.Add(blob);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CloseConnection();
    }

    public byte[] imageToByte(Image img)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

OpenConnection and closeconnection are simply conn.Open() and conn.Close().

The conversion however doesn't fail:[image]

But in the database I see this:[image]

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Your problem is the `UserImage = '@UserImage'`, replace it with `UserImage = @UserImage` or more conventional `UserImage = ?UserImage` and it will work. You're sending a string, hence 10 bytes.

Comment: just a side note, but are you sure you want to save as a blob.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347461/saving-images-files-or-blobs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
OpenConnection();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("", conn);
command.CommandText = "UPDATE User SET UserImage = '@UserImage' WHERE UserID = '" + UserID.globalUserID + "';";
byte[] data = imageToByte(img);
MySqlParameter blob = new MySqlParameter("@UserImage", MySqlDbType.Blob, data.Length);
blob.Value = data;

command.Parameters.Add(blob);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
CloseConnection();
```

With

```
var userImage = imageToByte(img);

OpenConnection();

var command = new MySqlCommand("", conn);

command.CommandText = "UPDATE User SET UserImage = @userImage WHERE UserID = @userId;";

var paramUserImage = new MySqlParameter("@userImage", MySqlDbType.Blob, userImage.Length);
var paramUserId = new MySqlParameter("@userId", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 256);  

paramUserImage.Value = userImage;
paramUserId.Value = UserID.globalUserID;    

command.Parameters.Add(paramUserImage);
command.Parameters.Add(paramUserId);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();  

CloseConnection();
```

You were sending `'@UserImage'` which is a 10 byte long string, remove the quotes and it should work.

Above code also uses parameters for both of your variables [which you should always do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

Either way hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

At first, i like to save blobs in the database good one :)

If you pass a parameter, do not encapsulate it in `'`, because than ADO.Net/MySql will not recognize it as a parameter, rather than a string:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE User SET UserImage = @UserImage WHERE UserID = '" + UserID.globalUserID + "';";
```

If you start using parameter, why not pass `UserID` also as a parameter:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE User SET UserImage = @UserImage WHERE UserID = @userId;";
```

This would make every think much clearer.

One important thing: If you store blobs in the database, never use `select * from ...`, because often you don't want to retrieve the blob, but you will with the star. This cause unnecessary trafic and decrease the performance.

Hope this helps!