# How to store images for android/ios backend

Tags: android, ios, image, laravel-5, backend

I am trying to implement an api for my dummy mobile app and I am using MySQL and Laravel 5 for that. I want to store images that user posts from mobile client. I wonder, what is the best practice for storing these images.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A way would be storing them as a blob in the MySQL database.

But I'd prefer to save them on your HDD or on S3 or similar services and just link to them when they are requested. This should be easier and more "natural". (For more info, here is a [related StackExchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347469/3975480)

I can suggest [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) for dealing with image saving through Laravel.